# Couldn't load a xcode project because it is already opened from another project or workspace

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, three20

I have a project that has one target dependency. The target dependency is dependent on a framework called Three20.

The dependency tree looks like this.

```
myProject
   -> myCustomFramework
         -> Three20
```

When I tried to build and run I get the following error message.

> Workspace Integrity Couldn't load Three20.xcodeproj because it is
>   already opened from another projet or workspace.

I have only one project open. Any suggestions on why I am getting this message?

Comment: close all projects and finderwindows then open ur project from finder

Comment: I've tried that. I also restarted my machine. Didn't work.

Comment: I'm also having this issue with Three20. It compiles, just throws these errors.

Comment: I tried restarting Xcode again and it appears to have worked. I'm not too sure why it didn't work the first time around.

Comment: Okay had the same exact issue with the same exact library, and force quitting xcode and reopening fixed it first shot.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Quitting the xcode completely and opening it up again worked.

Comment: My issue was that I tried open workspace without closing main project. How I fix it, I close all from Xcode (Xcode-Quit) and than open only workspace. If you try open workspace and you project together you will faced with error

Answer (score 24):

Quitting Xcode alone didn't work for me. What I did was:

1. File->Close Workspace/Project on every open workspace.
2. Xcode->Quit
3. Open Xcode again and open troublesome workspace

Comment: This happens when you open first a project withing the Workspace. And then try to open the workspace. I did not know I had to open the workspace but this solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I have close the Xcode completely but IT didn't work. I have killed the procces and It did finally!!!
 :-)

Comment: You probably close the Xcode window and no Xcode complitly. use Xcode -> Quit Xcode

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem in a case where I got a workspace working, closed it, copied the containing folder to a USB drive, then reopened. I got that message for one of the projects in the workspace. Closed, tried again, removed/re-added project - no luck. Closed, tried to open the project alone and got the message about it being open in another workspace - not true. Quit XCode, restarted by double-clicking my workspace in Finder, and all went well after.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. Fixed after updating of cocoa pods with pod update command.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the computer and try again opening the project :)