# Error in opening .xcworkspace

Tags: ios, signalr, afnetworking, cocoapods, socketrocket

I integrated pods in my project specifically SignalR, AFNetworking and SocketRocket. It was successfully installed, but when I opened .xcworkspace, this error shows:

[image]

[image: This is what the project navigator looks like]

Has anyone encountered this kind of error?
Thanks in advance.

Update:
My .xcodeproj has appeared. But the frameworks appear red. How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you kept the .xcodeproj open & trying to open the .xcworkspace file. Please close .xcodeproj file & then open the .xcworkspace again..

Comment: @NileshPatel no, I already closed and quitted xcode. My .xcodeproj doesn't seem to have arrow down to its left. I don't know why

Comment: please se the screenshot

Comment: Its not an error.. I can see the same thing in my project.. Are you not able run your project due to that?

Comment: I guess not. But I'm trying to build my project and I'm having this error:
 Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'AFHTTPClient.h' file not found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76863/discussion-between-nilesh-patel-and-apple).

Comment: @Apple Have you tried the answer described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10925617/657104) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [restarting Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7262107/657104)? If that doesn't work, I would try removing the `Pods/` folder and re-doing a `pod install`.

Comment: Sure, you can try that.

Comment: In the other thread, some people mentioned fixing it by first closing every workspace from the File menu before quitting Xcode. One even solved it by killing the process as well.

Comment: Hi @AppleRamos , can you please tell me how did you solve this, i am having the same issue.

Comment: Removing `Pods/` folder and running `pod install` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I did not have exactly the same error, but when I tried opening my .xcworkspace file, XCode did not display anything. I managed to solve the problem by:

- Deleting the .xcworkspace
- Deleting the Pods folder
- With my terminal, I navigated to the path where Pod file was and executed the `pod install` command, which re-generated the .xcworkspace file as well as the Pods folder

Then the project could open up just fine.

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. Not sure step #2 is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

An improvement to [サソリ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5382318/%E3%82%B5%E3%82%BD%E3%83%AA)'s answer. I had the same problem and what I did was,

- deleted .xcworkspace
- run `pod install` in terminal

Thats it. The newly created .xcworkspace works fine for me.