# Xcode 7.3 Couldn't load project

Tags: ios, xcode7.3, xcode-workspace

I have done some changes in functionality throughout the day.
After that I closed **workspace** and try to open it again it is showing `Couldn't load project`.

[image: Screenshot]

I've tried all solution available on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6820460/couldnt-load-a-xcode-project-because-it-is-already-opened-from-another-project) but none worked.
I'm using cocoa-pods in project.

Any other fix?

Comment: I guess your project file got corrupted, do you use any kind of versioning?

Comment: quit the xcode( cmd+q ) not just workspace and open it again!

Comment: @SanderSaelmans : Yes versioning via CornerStone SVN. Can't we repair corrupt file?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri : Read question carefully...I've already done this.

Comment: once I messed up my pbxproj file. I had the same issue. if you have way to verify that. at least that would be out of options

Comment: Try pod install again on your Pods with xcode quit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's an error when **project.pbxproj** failed to load the project for some reason.

**Solution 1 -)** Be sure that `project.pbxproj` file in project folder had **not** merge conflicts.

To do that, you can open it in a text editor. Then you need to look for interrupts like;

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======

>>>>>>> feature/...
```

After being sure conflicts are resolved, then you can go to source control and mark the conflicts resolved of the file (if you'd like to commit your resolved merge)

**Solution 2 -)** It can also be caused by missing fancy brackets in the same file that you may be familiar with JSON syntax. It generally happens due to wrong conflict resolutions.

**Solution 3 -)** If neither of the solutions above worked for you, you can ensure that you didn't delete something and corrupt the structure of project file by looking at the **difference** between your last correct project file in a branch and the current one. For my case, I generally solve the problem by checking if I deleted those lines by mistake.

```
    name = NameOfGroup;
    sourceTree = "<group>";
};
```

**Solution 4 -)** As a final solution, you may want to restore **project.pbxproj** file from a branch that it was not broken. Then, manually add references of recently added files to project.

Comment: Thanks @Yusuf. I found my solution by completing missing fancy brackets in the Project file.

Comment: Your solution + https://github.com/Karumi/Kin helped me to get rid of this trouble.

Answer (score 18):

i got same problem . i closed the project and reopened it .it worked for me.

Comment: may be your project file corrupted.check it

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem.

1. I first ran `pod repo update`. It takes a while to
   finish.
2. Then i ran `pod install`.
3. Open up your workspace
   and the problem should be fixed.

Comment: This at least show me where is the problem in `project.pbxproj`.

Answer (score 12):

It could be an issue with project.pbxproj file

[image]

I have solved this issue with this tools :

https://github.com/Karumi/Kin

After installation, i have performed a check :

[image]

See error was a bad merging on this error in project.pbxproj:

> ERROR: line 451:2 missing ';' at 'D062826E1DE2F43300818438'

Because XCode does not give a lot of information about this error, i advice to you to check your .pbxproj to be sure to exclude this possibility

Answer (score 3):

I had to upgrade Xcode before I could open the project (or any workspace containing it).

To know if you need to upgrade Xcode, try opening the project directly (rather than opening the workspace) and you should get the following error message:

> The project at '/path/to/your.xcodeproj' cannot be opened because it is in a future Xcode project file format. Adjust the project format using a compatible version of Xcode to allow it to be opened by this version of Xcode.

Comment: Although your inputs are related to Xcode version but this problem was raised while using Xcode 7. The only solution was to resolve conflicts in project file.

Answer (score 2):

There were conflict in my .pbxproj, once i remove the conflict and it worked !

Answer (score 1):

None of solutions above helped, after restart mac everything was fine